# Version of package postgresq-server-dev removed from Debian repository when archived

Tags: debian, repository, postgresql-9.6, debian-stretch

I am running a number of devices running Debian 9, that has recently been archived.
As a result, I have changed my sources.list to include `deb  http://archive.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free` instead of deb `http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free`.

On one of the devices, I have tried to install the packages I usually work with. I have been able to correctly install all of them but `postgresq-server-dev`. Its version `9.6.24-0+deb9u1` was available from Debian respository but it is not available anymore since the repository has been archived. As a result, the latest version available is `9.6.17-0+deb9u1`, which is not compatible with the default version of `postgresql-client-9.6` (`9.6.24-0+deb9u1`) because of a mismatch in the version of libpq5 they require as a dependecy.

```
user@device:~$ dpkg -s postgresql-client-9.6
Package: postgresql-client-9.6
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: database
Installed-Size: 4914
Maintainer: Debian PostgreSQL Maintainers <team+postgresql@tracker.debian.org>
Architecture: armhf
Multi-Arch: foreign
Source: postgresql-9.6
Version: 9.6.24-0+deb9u1
Provides: postgresql-client
Depends: libpq5 (>= 9.6.24), postgresql-client-common (>= 142~), libc6 (>= 2.15), libedit2 (>= 2.11-20080614), zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.3.3)
Suggests: postgresql-9.6, postgresql-doc-9.6
Description: front-end programs for PostgreSQL 9.6
 This package contains client and administrative programs for
 PostgreSQL: these are the interactive terminal client psql and
 programs for creating and removing users and databases.
 .
 This is the client package for PostgreSQL 9.6. If you install
 PostgreSQL 9.6 on a standalone machine, you need the server package
 postgresql-9.6, too. On a network, you can install this package on
 many client machines, while the server package may be installed on
 only one machine.
 .
 PostgreSQL is an object-relational SQL database management system.
Homepage: http://www.postgresql.org/

user@device:~$ sudo apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-9.6 libpq-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpq-dev : Depends: libpq5 (= 9.6.17-0+deb9u1) but 9.6.24-0+deb9u1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

#### Questions

- Is there a way to install version `9.6.24-0+deb9u1` of `postgresq-server-dev` and fix this issue?
- Is it expected that available package versions may change when Debian repository is archived?